# How can I filter out specific address type from this JSON result without empty arrays?

Tags: javascript, json, functional-programming

I have the following sample JSON and would like to retrieve results that matches specific `address_components.types`. The method I tried successfully retrieves the result, however it will contains some empty arrays. How can I edit it to return me only 2 matched arrays, without the 4 empty arrays? Preferably in a ES5 syntax.

```js
var sample = {
  "results": [{
    "address_components": [{
      "long_name": "33",
      "short_name": "33",
      "types": [
        "street_number"
      ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Parking Road",
      "short_name": "Parking Road",
      "types": [
        "route"
      ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Welling Park",
      "short_name": "Welling Park",
      "types": [
        "political",
        "sublocality",
        "sublocality_level_1"
      ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Jill Town",
      "short_name": "JT",
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Perak",
      "short_name": "Perak",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
      ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Malaysia",
      "short_name": "MY",
      "types": [
        "country",
        "political"
      ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "46666",
      "short_name": "46666",
      "types": [
        "postal_code"
      ]
    }]
  }]
}

var filtered = sample.results[0].address_components.map(function(address) {
  return address.types.filter(function(type) {
    return type === 'route' || type === 'sublocality_level_1'
  }).map(function() {
    return address;
  });
})

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Just call `filter` on the result array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter for what you want in the first place!

```
var filtered = sample.results[0].address_components.filter(function(address) {
  return address.types.indexOf('route') > -1 || address.types.indexOf('sublocality_level_1') > -1;
})
```

Working example below.

```js
var sample = {
  "results": [{
    "address_components": [{
      "long_name": "33",
      "short_name": "33",
      "types": [
        "street_number"
      ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Parking Road",
      "short_name": "Parking Road",
      "types": [
        "route"
      ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Welling Park",
      "short_name": "Welling Park",
      "types": [
        "political",
        "sublocality",
        "sublocality_level_1"
      ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Jill Town",
      "short_name": "JT",
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Perak",
      "short_name": "Perak",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
      ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Malaysia",
      "short_name": "MY",
      "types": [
        "country",
        "political"
      ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "46666",
      "short_name": "46666",
      "types": [
        "postal_code"
      ]
    }]
  }]
}

var filtered = sample.results[0].address_components.filter(function(address) {
  return address.types.indexOf('route') > -1 || address.types.indexOf('sublocality_level_1') > -1;
})

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me the existence of indexOf, I can't believe I left that out!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to keep the address components whose `types` array contains either `route` or `sublocality_level_1`:

```
let components = sample.results[0].address_components.filter(component => {
    return component.types.some(t => t == 'route' || t == 'sublocality_level_1');
});
```

Comment: Not a critique, I am curious: Why when using "*arrow*" notation do you then use a code block with an explicit return?

Comment: Because I find it the most readable variation in this instance, with all those long lines.